# Area of a rose function in the circle

Tags: integration, circles, area

[image]

I have a function : $$f(\theta) = 3\cdot \sin(2\theta)$$
The graph of the rose function is as shown in the photo.

In order to calculate the area of upper right  petal i have to calculate it from the type :

$$
\begin{align*}
A&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b}[f(\theta)]^2 d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}[3\cdot \sin(2\theta)]^2 d\theta \\
&= \frac{9\pi}{8}
\end{align*}
$$

My question is: If I want to calculate the full rose area I have to calculate the :

$$
\begin{align*}
A&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi}[3\cdot \sin(2\theta)]^2 d\theta \\
&= \frac{18\pi}{4}
\end{align*}
$$

Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you can check that it is $4\times \frac{9\pi}{8}$.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Given the symmetry you can simply multiply by $4$ too.

Comment: thanks mates @Tavish and Math Lover